# Drop Down Menu issues. Keeping it dropped in certain circumstances

Tags: jquery, menu, drop-down-menu

I have a horizontal drop-down menu on my website. It's currently only two levels deep:

```
<ul><li>Option 1
    <ul><li>Option 1.1
        <ul>
            <li>Option 1.1.1</li>
            <li>Option 1.1.2</li>
        </ul>
    </li></ul>
</li></ul>
```

The Option 1 layer is always visible. 1.1 is visible upon hover over Option 1 and Option 1.1.1 and 1.1.2 are visible upon hover over Option 1.1

The client has said that they love the drop down menu. However, to get from Option 1.1.1 to Option 1.1.2 involves you navigating the multi-levelled menu again and that's a mechanism they don't like.

I had the idea of detecting what Option page the user is on and then amending the classes so that they are constantly visible. For example: If I was on Option 1.1.1 page the full menu would still be visible allowing easy access to Option 1.1.2

Would it be feasible through JQuery and Javascript to return the Option from the URL and then searching through the multi-levelled menu to add classes to the menu allowing it to behave in a certain way.

I'm not sure where to begin with this.

My URLs are structured as below:

```
[root]/category.php?alias=option111
[root]/category.php?alias=option112
```

I'm not sure how I would search through the menu though. Could you provide some help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you would have to know which alias you're on. You can parse that to javascript using PHP or you can check the document.location.href and fix it with a regular expression.

For example if you found that the alias is option111, you'll have to trigger a mouseover on the menuitems that are needed to get to that menu.

```
$.document.ready(function() {

    //Fix something that 'alias' is an array and contains the numbers of menuitems that you use in your id structure of the menuitems.

    alias.each(function() {
        $('#menuitem'+$(this)).trigger('mouseover');
    });
});
```

This is just a concept you can use. I hope you can use this idea.

-edit after your comment-

It might be useful to give you're dropdownmenu id's which are similar to their place in the heirarchy of the . This way you can see which of the dropdownmenu items should be opened using the alias in the url. This way we can loop (we can do this using while, each or whichever you prefer).

```
var alias = document.location.href.slice(6,0); // getting the alias (ex: 111)
var i = 0;
while(i < alias.length) { //for each alias character (menu, submenu, subsubmenu, etc)
$('#menuitem'+alias.substring(0,i).trigger('mouseover'); //trigger the mouseover for ex #menuitem1, or #menuitem32, or #menuitem152
i++; //increment i to make the loop finite.
}
```

or, if you're mouseover event shows the menu for a short time, you can use 
`$('#menuitem'+alias.charAt(i)).css('display','block');` instead of

```
$('#menuitem'+alias.charAt(i)).trigger('mouseover');
```

Comment: It's the difficulty of looking through my multi-tiered list and picking which ones are related to the current one. How would I search through to add that trigger event? +1 for trigger which I didn't know existed (I'm new to JQuery)

Comment: the issue with trigger('mouseover') is that if the user touches the menu, any part of the menu with the cursor, it jumps and resets. I need it to stay there the entire time your on the page. I think it's clashing with the drop down menu plugin. I've tried .addClass() and style the class, I've tried actually setting the .css(), but none of this seems to affect it.

Comment: I see, so the plugin automatically hides the active menu items when the mouse is used to open any part of the menu? I don't know if this works, but you can try to make the new css styles that you create for the active menu items when opening the page set to !important. Javscript can not easily overwrite !important css statements, but I don't know if javascript can set them. Try $('#menuitem'+alias.charAt(i)).css('display','block !important'); I hope it fixes the problem.

Comment: Eventually I added a added a class '#menuitem'+alias as you suggested and used php to output the IDs that I needed i.e. 5 for the parent and 10 for the child. I then used JQuery to clone the menu that I needed and append it to my content. That way it would be out of the reach of the menu plugin. Then I set it to display:block.

Comment: Thanks for your help. You didn't solve my question exactly but you put me on the right track so I'll accept your answer anyway :) You gave me clues, which I sniffed and followed until I hit upon a solution. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using the menu dropdown that's going to be in jQuery UI 1.9 (and [already available](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.menu.js) in Github?)

You'd need to tweak styles to make your main menu horizontal (and always visible), or alternately treat each of your top level `<li>` elements as triggers for separate `$.menu()` items linked off their child `<ul>` elements.

I've put some demo code at http://jsfiddle.net/tcg2m/12/

It needs some work to figure out how to make the top level menu horizontal instead of vertical.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind, but I can't use it for my current project as I'm too far down the line now to be changing the menu. Thanks though

Comment: That demo code at http://jsfiddle.net/tcg2m/12/ does not seem to work any more. Is there revised demo / code else where?

Comment: @Wavesailor the linked plugins link to the latest code that use a function that's not in the older version of jQuery UI supported by jsfiddle.  It's all built-in in jQuery UI 1.9 now.  I've updated the fiddle, though - http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/tcg2m/20/